# Definitive way to stack table rows in responsive design - with or without media queries?

Tags: html, media-queries, responsive

I've read numerous articles detailing how to create stackable table rows for responsive design emails, but I am unable to get it to work.  I am working on an email and here is the code.  The section class=social is the one in question. In the original code which i am copying, they used divs.  it seems they coded it for the web rather than email.

My understanding is that tables without media queries are the best way to go for designing responsive HTML emails.  How would I do that in the email Im designing here?  Full code below.  Table in question is table class="social"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Really Good Emails</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
          background-color:#f7f7f7;
          color:#5f5f5f;
          font-family: Roboto,Tahoma,sans-serif;
              }
        h1 {
          color:#404040;
        }

        .button {
          opacity:1;
          transition:0.3s;
            }

        .button:hover {opacity:0.6}

        .header {
          background-image: url("http://i1.createsend1.com/ei/i/53/DC3/DE5/174640/csfinal/email-background2.jpg");
          border-spacing: 0px;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          padding-bottom:0px;
        }

        a {
          text-decoration:none;
          display: block;

          }
        .btn {
          opacity:1;
        }

        .btn:hover {
          opacity:.8;
        }

@media only screen and (max-width:510px)  {

    body {max-width: 100% !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}
    .header {max-width: 100% !important; padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}
    .header img {width:300px !important;height:auto !important;}
    .friday {max-width:100% !important;display:flex;align-items: center;padding-bottom:0px;}
    .friday img {max-width:100% !important;height:auto !important;}
    .advertise img {display:block !important; width:100% !important; height:auto !important; max-width:100% !important;height:auto !important;}
    .advertise {display:block !important; width:100% !important; height:auto !important; max-width:100% !important;
      height:auto !important;border-collapse: collapse !important; table-layout: fixed !important;border-spacing:0;}
    .friday h1 {padding: 0 0 0 15px !important;}
    .curved {display:none !important;}
     p {font-size:1rem !important;}
     td {max-width: 100% !important;}
    .footer p {font-size:.7rem !important;}
    .cliff {max-width:100% !important; padding-bottom:0px !important;}
    .social {max-width:100% !important; display:flex;align-items: center;flex-direction:column;}
    .social a {width:95%;}
    .space {display:none !important;}
    }



    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<table class="header" width="100%" bgcolor="#fe4c44" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 25px 0 25px 0; display:block;" align="center">
      <a href="https://reallygoodemails.com/?utm_campaign=complete-your-profile&utm_source=ReallyGoodEmails&utm_medium=email">
      <img style="display:block;" width="600px" height="64px" alt="Really Good Emails" src="http://i1.createsend1.com/ei/i/53/DC3/DE5/174640/csfinal/header_RGE-logo-9900000000079e3c.png">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <img class="curved" style="display:block; max-width:600px;" width="600px" height="32px" src="http://i2.createsend1.com/ei/i/53/DC3/DE5/174640/csfinal/top-rounded3-9900000000079e3c.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="friday" style="padding-bottom:0px;" align="center" width="600px" bgcolor="white">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" color="#5f5f5f;">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-txf0GL1wK4&feature=youtu.be"><img width="560px" height="398px" alt="Feedback Friday"
      src="http://i3.createsend1.com/ei/i/53/DC3/DE5/174640/csfinal/feedback-compressed-9900000000079e3c.png"></a>
      <h1 style="font-family: Roboto,Tahoma,sans-serif; font-size:1.5rem; line-height:30px;padding:0 15px 0 15px;color:#5f5f5f;" align="left">
        Template Eyes</h1>
      <p style="padding:0 15px 0 15px; line-height:25px;font-size:1.2rem;" color="#5f5f5f;" align="left">
        Not all pre-built email templates are created equal. Some are born with looks so dreamy that you hardly need to change a thing.
        Others, as we will see in today's <strong><em>Feedback Friday</em></strong>, may need some work done on them but can walk a line of being overdone -
        kind of like a movie star who gets too much plastic surgery.
      </p>
      <p style="padding:0 15px 0 15px; line-height:25px;font-size:1.2rem;" color="#5f5f5f;" align="left">This week we jump into a recently submitted B2B email to discuss where you can go wrong in those kinds of scenarios. (For clarity, we are talking about email template scenarios, not plastic surgery scenarios.)
      </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left" style="padding: 0 15px 0 15px;">
          <a class="button" style="padding: 12px 24px 12px 24px;border-radius: 4px; text-align:center;display:inline-block; background-color: #fe4c44;
          text-decoration:none; font-size: .8rem;line-height:24px;color: white;" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-txf0GL1wK4&feature=youtu.be" target="_blank">
  <strong>BE WISE & CUSTOMIZE</strong></a>
            </td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
    <img alt="bottom border of image" width="600px"align="center"
      src="http://i4.createsend1.com/ei/i/53/DC3/DE5/174640/csfinal/rounded-bottom_articles-fancy1-9900000000079e3c.png">
      </img>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="advertise" align="center" width="600px" bgcolor="#f7f7f7">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding:20px 0 20px 0; font-size:.7rem;" align="center">This email is supported by:</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom:35px;" align="center">
      <a href="https://iterable.com/demo-rge/?utm_medium=sponsoredemail&utm_source=really-good-emails&utm_campaign=demo"><img width="560"
        style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;"
      src="http://i5.createsend1.com/ei/i/53/DC3/DE5/174640/csfinal/ReallyGoodEmail_Banner_Animation_BlueBG_V1_L1R5-9900000000079e3c.gif"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="friday" style="padding-bottom:0px;" align="center" width="600px" bgcolor="white">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" color="#5f5f5f;">
      <h1 style="font-family: Roboto,Tahoma,sans-serif; font-size:1.5rem; line-height:30px;padding:0 15px 0 15px;color:#5f5f5f;" align="left">
        Inspiring Stuff</h1>
      <p style="padding:0 15px 0 15px; line-height:25px;font-size:1.2rem;" color="#5f5f5f;" align="left">
Here's what got us up in a state of mind surfing this week:
      </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a class="button" align="center" style="margin:10px; padding: 12px 24px 12px 24px;border-radius: 3px;border: 1px solid red;
        text-align:center;background-color: white;
      text-decoration:none; font-size: .8rem;line-height:24px;color: black;" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-txf0GL1wK4&feature=youtu.be"
      target="_blank">
      <strong> SHOULD BUTTONS BE ROUNDED OR SQUARE?</strong></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a class="button" align="center" style="margin:10px; padding: 12px 24px 12px 24px;border-radius: 3px;border: 1px solid red;
      text-align:center;background-color: white;
    text-decoration:none; font-size: .8rem;line-height:24px;color: black;" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-txf0GL1wK4&feature=youtu.be"
    target="_blank">
    <strong>⬛  WHAT'S THIS GONNA LOOK LIKE IN DARK MODE?</strong></a>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <a class="button" align="center" style="margin:10px; padding: 12px 24px 12px 24px;border-radius: 3px;border: 1px solid red;
    text-align:center;background-color: white;
  text-decoration:none; font-size: .8rem;line-height:24px;color: black;" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-txf0GL1wK4&feature=youtu.be"
  target="_blank">
  <strong> THE DESIGN SPRINT CHALLENGE OF NICK BRITO</strong></a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <a class="button" align="center" style="margin:10px; padding: 12px 24px 12px 24px;border-radius: 3px;border: 1px solid red;
    text-align:center;background-color: white;
  text-decoration:none; font-size: .8rem;line-height:24px;color: black;" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-txf0GL1wK4&feature=youtu.be"
  target="_blank">
  <strong> PRESENTING CONFLICTING OPTIONS IN EMAIL</strong></a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <a class="button" align="center" style="margin:10px; padding: 12px 24px 12px 24px;border-radius: 3px;border: 1px solid red;
    text-align:center;background-color: white;
  text-decoration:none; font-size: .8rem;line-height:24px;color: black;" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-txf0GL1wK4&feature=youtu.be"
  target="_blank">
  <strong> COLORFUL GRADIENT CARDS</strong></a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
<img alt="bottom border of image" width="600px"align="center"
  src="http://i4.createsend1.com/ei/i/53/DC3/DE5/174640/csfinal/rounded-bottom_articles-fancy1-9900000000079e3c.png">
  </img>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="friday" align="center" width="600px" bgcolor="#f7f7f7">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <h2 style="padding:0 15px 0 15px; line-height:25px;font-size:1.2rem;" color="#5f5f5f;" align="center">Follow Us off the Cliff</h2>
    <p style="padding:0 15px 0 15px; line-height:25px;font-size:1rem;" color="#5f5f5f;" align="center">
      We know what your mother said. If Really Good Emails jumped off a cliff would you go with them? Yes, of course you would. Don’t be silly.</p>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="social" align="center" width="600px" bgcolor="#f7f7f7">
    <tr>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#38A1F3" style="border-radius:4px;">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" style="font-size: .8rem; color: white;
    text-decoration: none; text-decoration: none;display:inline;padding:10px 30px 10px 30px;"><strong>TWITTER</strong></a>
        </td>
    <tr>
      <td> &nbsp; </td>
    </tr>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#C92228" style="border-radius:4px;padding:10px;">
      <a href="#" target="_blank" style="font-size: .8rem; color: white;
    text-decoration: none; text-decoration: none;display:inline;"><strong>PINTEREST</strong></a>
        </td>
        <tr>
          <td> &nbsp; </td>
        </tr>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="black" style="border-radius:4px;padding:10px;">
      <a href="#" target="_blank" style="font-size: .8rem; color: white;
    text-decoration: none; text-decoration: none;display:inline;"><strong>CODEPEN</strong></a>
        </td>
         </tr>
</table>

<table style="padding: 25px 0 25px 0" align="center" width="100%" bgcolor="white">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <h3>Design Better.  Spam Never.</h3>
      <p>Update Subscription&nbsp;-&nbsp;Articles & Interviews&nbsp;-&nbsp;Free Resources&nbsp;-&nbsp;View Online</p>
        </td>
</table>

<table class="friday footer" align="center" width="600px" bgcolor="#f7f7f7">
  <tr>
    <td style="color:#9a9ca0; padding: 25px; font-size:.7rem!important; line-height:20px;">
      <p style="font-size:.7rem;">We sent this email to you because of your insatiable thirst for email inspiration that does not make your eyes burn
      like you were thrown into a lake of sliced raw onions—ugh, the worst.</p>

      <p>All this shiznit is © Really Good Emails 2018. All these images belong to us and our moms all said this is
        one instance where we don't have to share if we don't want to. All the emails apparently still belong to the
        individual companies, we just sort of "web photographed" them when they put them in our email inbox. </p>

      <p>If you want to send us gifts, fan mail, or anything that does not include stalking or us waking up with you in our
        living room—you can find us at 1040 W Washington St, Greenville, SC, USA  29601</p>

      <p>Or, if you're just tired of hearing from us, you can unsubscribe too.</p></td>
  </tr>

</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This GitHub repo may be of help to you:
https://github.com/tutsplus/creating-a-future-proof-responsive-email-without-media-queries

Basically, you need to do "columns" of `display: inline-block;` with a fixed `max-width`.
E.g: if you set 2 elements of `max-width: 300px;` as `inline-block`s, then at smaller screens such as mobile; when the screen is 600px or less, the columns will instead stack on top of each other.